# Can I run a packaged Chrome app as a tab in the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I use a few packaged Chrome apps, namely [Wunderlist for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wunderlist-for-chrome/ojcflmmmcfpacggndoaaflkmcoblhnbh?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher), [Text](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text/mmfbcljfglbokpmkimbfghdkjmjhdgbg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher), and [Google Keep](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher).

Packaged apps launch a new window when you click on their icon on the New Tab page:

[image: animated screenshot showing packaged app behavior]

I keep a Chrome window maximized on a second monitor at all times. I want to keep window switching on this monitor to a minimum, and the fact that these apps require spawning a new window is rather frustrating.

**Is there any way to launch these packaged Chrome apps in a tab instead of a new window?**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14298166/632951

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298166/run-chrome-packaged-apps-inside-of-browser-tab No, it is not possible by design.

Comment: @Pacerier Broken Links! Solution not even given. Link only given and the links is gone, gone, gone. You'd think that a techie knows that links are temporary.

Comment: I've looked and looked. Still very valid as I'm looking for the same thing. Google examples are horrible; they can't think outside their cool little boxes.

Comment: @ejbytes The link works fine for me.

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz Yes, your link works. It's the links that your links, link to; which make your link a link to no information available. Follow your link to the "information". The answer at the end of your link leads to dead erro:404's. The accepted answer by "mangini" which is just a solution made of links with no real content.

Answer (score 0):

"No, it is not possible by design. Chrome packaged apps run separately from the browser and have no access to browser-specific features, like tabs."

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298166/run-chrome-packaged-apps-inside-of-browser-tab